# Passing entire Array as a parameter into a function

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am trying to pass an entire array into a my function, but I am getting currently getting the error:

```
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:4:18: error: expected expression before ']' token 
method(myArray[]);
              ^
test.c: At top level:
test.c:8:6: warning: conflicting types for 'method' [enabled by default]
void method(int arr[]){
     ^
test.c:4:3: note: previous implicit declaration of 'method' was here
method(myArray[]);
^
test.c: In function 'method':
test.c:9:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf' [enabled by default]
printf("DATA: %d",arr[2]);
^
```

This is my code (a simplified version of what I'm trying to do that throws up the same error:

```
int main(){
  int myArray[3];
  myArray[2]=12;
  method(myArray[]);
}

void method(int arr[]){
  printf("DATA: %d",arr[2]);
}
```

Comment: A forward declaration may help

Comment: this is the correct way, `method(myArray);` remove the brackets

Comment: You are in in some sense thinking of it wrong when you describe it as "passing an entire array" since only a pointer as opposed to the whole array is actually passed.

Comment: Ddeja vu - twice..  Must be 'Pass Array into Function' day.

Answer (score 6):

When passing an array to a function, you don't need the `[]` after it.  Just using the name of the array is sufficient.

Also, you need to either define or declare your functions before they're used, and you need to `#include <stdio.h>` so the compiler knows the definition of `printf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void method(int arr[]);

int main(){
  int myArray[3];
  myArray[2]=12;
  method(myArray);
}

void method(int arr[]){
  printf("DATA: %d",arr[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

More than one point to be mentioned here,

- Firstly, include the required header files which contains the function signature of the library functions you're going to use.
- Secondly, either forward declare the function prototype or define the function before usage. Be aware, the *ancient* implicit declaration rule has been officially dropped from the C standards.
- Thirdly, change

  ```
  method(myArray[]);
  ```

  to

  ```
  method(myArray);
  ```

  as the array name itself gives you the base address of the array, which is basically what you need to pass.